# Manipulating an array afterward so that the rows and column depends on the size of two strings

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, python-3.8

I am trying to manipulate array2 so that the row and column is dependent on the len of the strings as for array1

```
str1 = "Hi"
str2 = "Bye"
array1 = [[[0, 0] for y in range(len(str2)+1)] for x in range(len(str1)+1)]
print(array1) 
#output: [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]

array2 = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
#want array2 to implement same format as array1 where the row and column is determined by the len of str1 and str2
temp = [[[array2[i], array2[j]] for y in range(len(str2)+1)] for x in range(len(str1)+1)] #does not work
```

I tried to remove some brackets from temp however, did not work.

I tried to manipulate the method I used for array1, but did not work. I was expecting the rows and columns to be dependent on the len of the strings as for array2.

Answer (score 0):

The current code has no idea what to do with `array2[i], array2[j]` cause neither `i` nor `j` have been defined.

This code is working as expected (I've organized the output for better readability):

```
str1 = "Hi"
str2 = "Bye"
array1 = [[[0, 0] for y in range(len(str2)+1)] for x in range(len(str1)+1)]
print(array1) 
#output is 4x3: [
#[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
#[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]

array2 = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
temp = [[[0, 0] for y in range(len(str2)+1)] for x in range(len(str1)+1)] 
#output is 4x3: [
#[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
#[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

If you want to use a certain set of numbers from the array, you need to change the code to:

```
i, o = 0, 1
temp = [[[array2[i], array2[j]] for y in range(len(str2)+1)] for x in range(len(str1)+1)]
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, please provide further explanation